# How to access search history?

Tags: spacemacs, search, history

I have spacemacs and when I search for a word using `/` once it turns out that I can't access it later on using the up arrow. This feature is present in vim so how do I cycle through search history after hitting `/` ?

Comment: I am not using spacemacs, but in vanilla emacs while using incremental search (`C-s` or `C-r`) you can cycle through the search ring via `M-p` and `M-n`.

Comment: ^ this worked for me. My meta is Esc so it was Esc-p or Esc-n

Comment: This should've been an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To enable this feature in Spacemacs add `(setq-default evil-search-module 'evil-search)` in `dotspacemacs/user-init ()` section.

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: this worked for me after restarting Emacs.